# Finding a basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find a basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Shouldn't the basis just be $\{\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3}\}$? since they are linearly independent with respect to the rationals?

Comment: How do you write $\sqrt{2}\sqrt[3]{3}$ as a linear combination of $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt[3]{3}$ ? (and that's not the only element you're missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the set $B = \{1,\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{3}, \sqrt[3]{9}, \sqrt{2}\sqrt[3]{3}, \sqrt{2}\sqrt[3]{9}\}$ is a linearly independent, and spanning set that you can check yourself. Thus this set is the basis.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested basis has $2$ elements and so cannot work since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3})$ has dimension at least $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ because of $\sqrt[3]{3}$.

A basis is $\{ u^i v^j : u=\sqrt2, v=\sqrt[3]{3}, i=0,1, j=0,1,2 \}$.